# update, dpgk broken

Tags: 14.04, kernel, dpkg, dependencies

I just upgraded to 14.04 now when I try to upgrade I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic : Depends: linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.55.62) but 3.13.0.57.64 is installed
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-55-generic but it is not installed
 linux-headers-server : Depends: linux-headers-3.2.0-79-generic but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

How do I deal with this?

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Did not work, I got things like     pkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-3.13.0-55-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-3.13.0-55-generic is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

(Not enough rep to add as comment)

Have you checked `/etc/apt/sources.list` to see that there arent't any old sources still hanging around?